# Java How to Display a Manual

Tags: java, pdf, manual, adobe-reader

I am making a manual for one of my applications. I was wondering the best way to display a manual using Java.

My idea is to create something like how Adobe Reader shows PDF files. The "map" of the document is on the left and the contents of the "chapter" are on the right.

How would I go about replicating this?

Comment: Is this a web app or desktop? What format is the documentation in?

Comment: This is a downloadable app. The current documentation is a really hard to navigate txt file. This is why I am hoping to convert it into a really nice, built-in, display.

Comment: Have no idea how that happened - but here is the real link - http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javahelp/

Comment: What you do in your free time, I do not want to know ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just create a PDF file, and opening it with the [Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class. The user's preferred PDF viewer would open the manual.

Or you could host the manual in HTML format on a publicly available web site, and use the same class to browse to the appropriate URI (which would have the advantage of being able to have a more contextual help, by linking to an appropriate URL).

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to make it built-in?

Comment: And ... how do I make a map to move around the PDF file?

Comment: built-in: it depends on how the app is released. You could just put the manual along with your jar files in a zip file, or use an installer. regarding the map, I guess you mean the table of contents on the right? If so, it just depends on the tool you use to make the PDF.